# How to use deep linking with posting photo

Tags: facebook, deep-linking

I have integrated facebook to my android App, and posting through the App. On below posted photo by my application I see "posted XX minutes ago via APPNAME", clicking 'APPNAME' no reaction. How can I change this link to my google play for example.

So how for example instagram or other apps redirect "via app" to their sites ?

I want my app to be able to make a share on Facebook which will appear as a link via my page. Is it possible?

I used to facebook sdk v2.0 and referenced below site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/ I've set the below information . Settings -> Basic -> app -> Website with Facebook Login, Mobile Web, Native Android App.

But, page didn't redirect in case of Native Android Facebook app. I can't link To my native App.

Comment: If you have got any solution please share... I am also looking out for same.. but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a Facebook app page to get the via app name feature.

You will also have to specify native app link in the facebook app, save a key hash and specify the  Launcher activity name in the facebook app to launch the app if it is installed on the android device.

If the app is not installed,clicking on the post will open the play store link.